# How to keep a value as selected in Spring form:options?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc

```
<form:select path="timer" id="time">

            <form:option value="0">09:00 AM</form:option>
            <form:option value="1">10:00 AM</form:option>
            <form:option value="2">11:00 AM</form:option>
            <form:option value="4">01:00 PM</form:option>
            <form:option value="3">12:00 PM</form:option>
            <form:option value="5">02:00 PM</form:option>
            <form:option value="6">03:00 PM</form:option>
            <form:option value="7">04:00 PM</form:option>
            <form:option value="8">05:00 PM</form:option>
            <form:option value="9">06:00 PM</form:option>
        </form:select>
```

How to keep 03:00 PM as selected? This code is placed in my jsp.

Comment: Are you using JSTL ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring will automatically make the correct `<option>` selected if the value for `timer` in your model matches the `value` attribute for that `<form:option>`.

So it depends how you're populating your model and what your form is bound to but the fundamental answer is set `timer` to `6` in your model.

E.g. you might have code like this in your controller:

```
model.addAttribute("timer",6);
```

Comment: I have included value="8", but this did not work. Whatever I have given are hardcoded contents of the dropdown.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your comment - where did you include `value="8"`? And I don't understand the second sentence. You should include the relevant parts of your java code in the question, it would help in getting a more specific answer

Comment: Oops, Sorry!! I meant I have added <form:select path="timer" id="time" value="6">.But this did not work.

Comment: The hardcoded values are the contents of the dropdown :)

Comment: You need to set the value of `timer` in your model before the JSP is invoked. This could be done programmatically in your controller, bound to request parameters/session objects, etc... It all depends on how your application is built and where that value is supposed to come from. I've added an example above